# How to update Laravel relation's table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

There are 2 models:

`Product` and `Product_Images`

```
class Product extends Eloquent { 
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function images(){
        return $this->hasMany('product_image');
    }

    public function brand(){
        return $this->belongsTo('brand');
    }
}

class Product_Image extends Eloquent { 
    protected $table = 'product_images';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function images(){
        return $this->hasMany('product_image');
    }
}
```

I can do update or insert data to this models

```
$product = new Product;
$product->title = $data['title'];
$product->alias = $data['alias'];
$product->short_description = $data['short_description'];
$product->price = $data['price'];
$product->brand_id = $data['brand_id'];
$product->description = $data['description'];
$product->published = 1;
$product->save();
foreach($data['images'] as $k => $v){
    if($data['main'] == $k){
        $product->images()->save(
            new Product_Image(['image' => $v,'main' => 1])
        );  
    }else{
        $product->images()->save(
            new Product_Image(['image' => $v,'main' => 0])
        );
    }
}
```

but when users try to edit the product, users may delete the existing images and try to add new ones and send the form. Which way should I follow for update the images relations. Should I delete all images related to product and create new ones ? this looks like bad practice to me, is there any best for this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your relation is wrong I think you have a one to many relation with product and image

so this should be

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('product_image');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);//import your product class with use
}
```

Also you are wrongly defining your relations. In your relation you will define the class optionally in some situations you can pass foreign key and local key and table names see [Defining Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

This should be

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('product_image');
}
public function brand(){
    return $this->belongsTo('brand');
}
```

This

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product_Image::class);//import class
}
public function brand(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);//import Brand class
}
```

Also you can simplify your code here

```
       if($data['main'] == $k){
            $product->images()->save(
                new Product_Image(['image' => $v,'main' => 1])
            );  
        }else{
            $product->images()->save(
                new Product_Image(['image' => $v,'main' => 0])
            );
        }


        $product->images()->save(
            new Product_Image(['image' => $v,'main' => (int)($data['main'] == $k)])
        );
```

Comment: Thank you! i applied your changes, and learned some good thing from it. Still I don't know how to update images related to products. Should I delete all images and add new ones from the form?